# How to select a symbolic link in a dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, symlink, mklink

I'm working on a small program that can create symbolic links.
Currently you could select a source and a target folder via FolderBrowserDialog.
The source gets copied into the target, deleted and replaced with an symbolic link.

Now I want the program to detect if source is already an symbolic link, but FolderBrowserDialog returns the target path when a link gets selected.
Is there a possibility to get the full path to the link (e.g. C:\path\to\) instead of the target path?

I only found a sample project that returns if a given path is a symlink but the program iterates over all directories via Directory.GetDirectories (which also returns the path to symlinks). But there is no way for a user to select a link via dialog.

Comment: As far as I know, .Net is still not good when it comes to support of links. I guess, there's no way to work with symlink itself via FolderBrowserDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov mentioned, it is not possible to select a Symlink in .Net.